# Why there is a need to use Object.create() in prototype interitance

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

I was looking at an inheritance example using prototypes as below:

```js
function Person(name){
   this.name = name
}

function Student(name){
  Person.call(this, name)
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)
Student.prototype.constructor = Student

let jim = new Student("Jim")
```

My question is, why there is a need to set the prototype using `Object.create(Person.prototype)` Why not simply setting it like `Person.prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
Student.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

and next move try to extend it:

```
Student.prototype.a = function(....
```

You will be affecting `Person.prototype` as well(since it's strictly the same exact object after assignment)